# SELECT a subset of records from Table A that match two columns in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of users in a database table called `Users` (SQL Server 2008 R2).  In addition to the user's `UserName`, there are two fields that classify the user - for simplicity we'll say `Department` and `JobTitle`.

```
|  UserName  |  Department  |  JobTitle  |
------------------------------------------
|    Joe     |     IT       |  SysAdmin  |
|    Jim     |     IT       |    DBA     |
|    Jeff    |    Sales     |  SalesMgr  |
|    Mack    |    Sales     |    Rep     |
```

I also have a table, `ActiveJobs`, that lists certain combinations of `Department` and `JobTitle` that I actually care about.

```
|  Department  |  JobTitle  |
-----------------------------
|     IT       |  SysAdmin  |
|    Sales     |  SalesMgr  |
|    Sales     |    Rep     |
```

I want to select each of the records from `Users` that matches the *combination* of `Department` / `JobTitle` in `ActiveJobs`.  I thought this query would do it:

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
INNER JOIN ActiveJobs DEP
ON Users.Department = DEP.Department
INNER JOIN ActiveJobs JOB
ON Users.JobTitle = JOB.JobTitle
```

But that returns the same `User` record more than once in many cases (which I think is caused by the duplicates in the `Department` column - but I don't really understand why).  For the example above, I'm getting (Joe, Joe, Jim, Mack) even though I was hoping to just get (Joe, Jim, Mack).

What query would get the **subset** of `User` records that has a matching *combination* of `Department` and `JobTitle` in `Active Jobs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an "AND" in your join clause instead of joining twice.

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
INNER JOIN ActiveJobs DEP
ON Users.Department = DEP.Department AND Users.JobTitle = DEP.JobTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like one join on two attributes would work, rather than two joins on one attribute each. Can you JOIN ON ... AND ... ? (Away from computer)